# Android license test ccounts are charged

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm testing my android app's in-app billing with google license test accounts. The app itself is in alpha only. When the google play popup comes with the product information, I get the message saying, "This is a test account, you will not be charged", but then I still get the transaction completion messages from my Credit Card's issuing bank. So everytime I have  to login to the google developer wallet site and cancel the order. Is this how it works or am I missing something here?? Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue, i also cancelled the order from merchant account. It might be we are not waiting for the completion of transaction in the merchant account. you can wait for the completion and can check does it complete the transaction or cancel it by itself.